# How to navigate from one screen to another in SwiftUI Apple Watch App

Tags: navigation, apple-watch, swiftui

I'm having problems doing navigation in a SwiftUI Apple Watch app. There's minimal resources online regarding this.

I mostly understand how to create SwiftUI views, but I'm not sure what the best way to navigate from SwiftUI view to another SwiftUI view is.

Is there a way to push a user to another SwiftUI screen when they tap a button?

Comment: NavigationView? I'm not sure about the watch but since the framework is declarative it should work cross platform

Comment: That would make sense, but nope. I've tried using NavigationView, but when you add it, you get the message "NavigationView is unavailable in WatchOS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To provide a very basic example how it can work on watchOS.

```
struct ListView: View {
var body: some View {



    List{

        RowView(title: "Row 1")
        RowView(title: "Row 2")
        RowView(title: "Row 3")
        RowView(title: "Row 4")

    }
    .listStyle(.carousel)


    }
}
struct RowView: View {
    let title: String
    var body: some View {

    NavigationLink(destination: Text("Detail \(title)")) {

        Text(title)
            .frame(height: 80, alignment: .topTrailing)
            .listRowBackground(
                Color.blue
                    .cornerRadius(12)
        )
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by initializing a [NavigationLink](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink) with your destination view. Its documentation is minimal at the moment, but the tutorial [Building Lists and Navigation](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/building-lists-and-navigation) and [WWDC session SwiftUI on watchOS](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019-219/?time=440) may be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace NavigationView by List, and it works like a charm

```
struct ContentView : View{
    var body : some View {
        List{
            VStack{
        NavigationLink(destination: BPView()) {
            Text("Some text")
                .foregroundColor(Color.blue);
        }
            NavigationLink(destination:myView()) {
                Text("Show text here")
                .foregroundColor(Color.blue);
            }
            }}

    }
}
```